# Why did they cut only part of the pant like this?

Tags: plot-explanation, monsters-ball

In *Monster's Ball* (2001), why did they cut only part of the jeans pant of a criminal like this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because **that's where they attach the electrode** when someone is executed on an electric chair. From the [Wikia page](http://answers.wikia.com/wiki/How_does_the_electric_chair_work) about electric chairs *[Warning: A Bit Graphic]*:

> In order to go to the chair, the prisoner must have their head freshly shaved only minutes before the execution. They also have to have cotton stuffed up their anus, in order to keep them from messing themselves, since the electricity takes away their control of their bowels. Next, **they have to have their legs shaved, so an electrode can be placed on their right leg,** and all facial hair is shaved. **They have a slit cut in the leg of their pants so the electrode can make contact with their bare skin.** Once that is finished, they are led to the chair.

Sometimes, instead of a slit, the pant leg is rolled up or, like in this particular case, cut off altogether. The idea behind using both the head and calf electrodes is for the current to pass through the body, hitting all the major organs along the way.

Comment: Hmmm...  So did they muck up?  That guy's **left** pant leg is cut off, not his **right** as stated in the citation.  I wonder whether it matters which leg is used?

Comment: I don't think it matters at all. I'm not sure *why* they say it's the right leg there, but maybe someone could enlighten me.